# When pressing Back button, what determines whether the browser hits the server again or re-renders what it had in memory?

Tags: caching, browser, http-headers, back-button

I'm developing a Rails 3 app, and I noticed that when pressing Back, the browser re-shows the page it already has in memory, instead of hitting the server.

That said, I'm 99% confident that in previous apps I've developed, this wasn't the case, and the browser would hit the server again.

So, provided I remember correctly, this must be some HTTP header / something that Rails is setting to makes things snappier.

I'd like to know what it is since this is kind of problematic for us in pages where we modify the DOM heavily through JS, and the user ends up pressing Back and getting the "original" version served, instead of the heavily modified one, which is really confusing in some cases.

---

**EDIT:** I thought doing this had fixed the problem, but it didn't:

```
def force_no_cache_on_back_button
  #expires_in -1, :public => false
  headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
  headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache; no-store; private; must-revalidate; max-age=0'
  headers['Expires'] = 1.day.ago.to_s
end
```

Surprisingly that *does* work over HTTPS with a *broken* SSL certificate (we use self-signed for our staging server), but it doesn't work in production, with a "good" SSL cert. Which is just weird.

Any other ideas?

---

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: Test in different browsers. Is the behavior consistent?

Comment: Very. At least the new behaviour (not re-hitting the server). As for the old one, I can't easily test it again, it's an old project.

Comment: How does the difference between cache-served and server-served manifest? You're getting the "original" unmodified page in both cases.

Comment: User loads a page. Page shows an empty list. Through Ajax, they add things to the list. If the server were to re-render the page, it'd render a full list. If they navigate away and back, they get the empty list again

Comment: How does the server know which items were added to the list via Ajax?

Comment: It just renders the list of things according to the database. This is highly not relevant to my question

Comment: So when the user adds items to the list on the page, those changes are uploaded via Ajax and stored in a database on the server, so when the user visits the page again, the changes are retrieved from the database and displayed on the page, correct?

Comment: What are the cache related response headers of the page? (Browser's dev tools > Network tab) Setting `Cache-Control max-age=0` forces the browser to always perform a server-request. I'm not sure though if that applies for the Back button as well.

Comment: It doesn't apply to the back button

Comment: You could have a JavaScript function that executes on page init and checks via Ajax if there are additional items in the server database. Btw, my approach would be to have data operations done exclusively via JavaScript/Ajax (initial load, adding, removing, etc).

Comment: Yes, but none of that answers my question.

Comment: There are a bunch of techniques in the search results [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=force+server+request+on+back+button)